# How to change font size in html?

Tags: html, fonts, size

I am trying to make a website and I want to know how to change the size of text in a paragraph. I want paragraph 1 to be bigger than paragraph 2. It doesn't matter how much bigger, as long as it's bigger. How do I do this?

My code is below:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
  p {
    color: red;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can use `rem` as scale for your font size for more flexibility and it's more dynamic.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Give them a class and add your style to the class.

```
<style>
  p {
    color: red;
  }
  .paragraph1 {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  .paragraph2 {
    font-size: 13px;
  }
</style>

<p class="paragraph1">Paragraph 1</p>
<p class="paragraph2">Paragraph 2</p>
```

Check this **[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Xandour/jfCzv/)**

Comment: It's browser specific.  If you want a default for across browsers, you should set it yourself.

Answer (score 13):

Or add styles inline:

```
<p style="font-size:18px">Paragraph 1</p>
<p style="font-size:16px">Paragraph 2</p>
```

Comment: Thanks. It works perfectly. Do you have any idea what the default font size is. I think it's around 16/17px...

Comment: Inline styles are bad!

Answer (score 7):

If you're just interested in increasing the font size of just the first paragraph of any document, an effect used by online publications, then you can use the first-child pseudo-class to achieve the desired effect.

```
p:first-child
{
   font-size:   115%; // Will set the font size to be 115% of the original font-size for the p element.
}
```

However, this will change the font size of every p element that is the first-child of any other element. If you're interested in setting the size of the first p element of the body element, then use the following:

```
body > p:first-child
{
   font-size:   115%;
}
```

The above code will only work with the p element that is a child of the body element.

Comment: If we combine and configure it with `rem` and use `rem` as scale for font size and other related size figures it would be more flexible and dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this without adding classes...

```
p:first-child {
    font-size: 16px;
}

p:last-child {
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

or

```
p:nth-child(1) {
    font-size: 16px;
}

p:nth-child(2) {
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in HTML. You can in CSS. Create a new CSS file and write:

```
p {
 font-size: (some number);
}
```

If that doesn't work make sure you don't have any "pre" tags, which make your code a bit smaller.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting a style in your paragraph tag. For example if you wanted to change the font size to 28px.

```
<p style="font-size: 28px;"> Hello, World! </p>
```

You can also set the color by setting:

```
<p style="color: blue;"> Hello, World! </p>
```

However, if you want to preview font sizes and colors (which I recommend doing) before you add them to your website and use them. I recommend testing them out beforehand so you pick a good font size and color that contrasts well with the background. I recommend using this site if you wish to do so, couldn't find anything else: http://fontpreview.herokuapp.com/