# change font size in HTML5 using knitr only

Tags: html, knitr, slidify

I am using `knitr` to generate HTML5 slides, and use the following codes:

```
library(knitr)
knit("file.Rmd")
pandoc("file.md", format="dzslides")
```

However, the font sizes (for normal text and R codes) are larger so I hope to make them smaller. I know there is a way of using `slidify` to convert `.Rmd` file to HTML5, but I wonder if there is an easier way to make the adjustment only using `knitr`? For some reason, I don't want to use `slidify` for now.

Currently I put the following codes at the end of my `.Rmd` file:

```
<!--pandoc
s:
S:
i:
mathjax:
-->
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a dirty way to solve this issue：just use raw HTML5 in your RMD document and it always works.

Check [How to change font size in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18007440/how-to-change-font-size-in-html5) and just define your font size in a custom chuck at the beginning of your RMD files.

```
<style>
p {
   color: red;
  }
.paragraph {
   font-size: 18px;
  }
</style>
```

Then use`<p class="paragraph">Paragraph A</p>` in your files.

I know this method actually discard the cons of `markdown`. However, when the default way has close the door, the only path might go to the raw.